# Need help on with this problem on linear mapping of co-ordinates of square.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a homework question. If I could get a hint or solution for the first part, it would be really helpful. I couldn't attend the lecture due to my illness. [image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing the initial figure and the final figure and trying to see how you would get there?

Comment: Yes I drew the same..for the first it's a translation along 1,1 and the other one is deformed and translated to right by 1

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the concept of finding $A$ and $\vec{v}$, and see whether you can apply it

$A$ represents deformations. These type of transformations include stretching and rotations. $\vec{v}$ represents translations, which will be the same for all points of the figure.

Since $A$ cannot remap the origin, to find $\vec{v}$ is trivial, just see the difference of the origin (or in this case, the first point of the square)

For $(1)$, $\vec{v} = (1,1)$ and for (2), $\vec{v} = (2,0)$

Now, you can subtract $\vec{v}$ from each point to see what just the $A$ transformation will give you. For tthe first part, you get the original square, so $A$ is identity

For the second part, you get a parallelogram which shares the base of the square, but shifts outward in linear proportion to $y$ as you go up. This can be written as $(x,y) \to (x+y,y)$

Hence $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I do not really understand the second part. Also, how do i represent this transformation. Thanks

Comment: For the second part, after removing the translation, you get a skewed parallelogram, right?